# Wrapping <p> and all subsequent <p> tags until the tag changes

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I need a way to use wrap all `<p>` tags until the last closing `</p>` tag before a tag change. So Every P tag that has either no tag before it, or a tag other than `<p>` would start the match. Every tag ending in `</p>` but followed by a tag that is not a paragraph marks the end of that match.

I tried using this:

```
$content = preg_replace( "/(<(p|ul)>[\s\S]*?(?=<h\d.*?>|<\/ul>))/Si", '<div class="content-block">$0</div>', $content );
```

but that only works if the paragraph tag is between header tags.  I need something more flexible.  Here is an example of what I mean (sorry if this is rough, not sure how to visually portray what I need):

```
<div class="wrapper">
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
<h2>Information<h2>
<div class="wrapper">
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
<h2>Another Header Here</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
<h3>Header Three</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
<p></p>
<ul>List Item</ul>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit and add an example of `$content` ?

Comment: can you put your expected output?

Comment: For parsing HTML with Regex please [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454) (TL;DR: don't)

Comment: The expected output would be the <p> tags wrapped in a div.  Like: <div class="wrapper"><p></p><p></p></div>

Comment: Perhaps there's a less problematic way of getting the desired effect. Why do you want to wrap the `<P>`s in `<DIV>`s?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself.  I needed a more generic selector, to select everything except specific tags.  Here is what I came up with:

```
$content = preg_replace( "/((<p|<ul|<ol|<blockquote)(?:(?!\n<h|\n<table).)*)/sm", '<div class="content-block">$0</div>', $content );
```